# Model not inheriting User data

Tags: django

So I am working with built-in Django login forms and I want my blogger model to inherit all the users created using the form but it is not showing up in the blogger model.

**Models**

```
class Blogger(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='following', symmetrical=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**View for the sign up**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/blog')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'winterblog/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

**Django form used**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/blog')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'winterblog/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Thanks a lot!

[image: User]

[image: Blogger]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signup view does not create `Blogger` instance. You can create blogger record for new user inside view:

```
def signup(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
        Blogger.objects.create(user=user)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/blog')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'winterblog/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Another option is add [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/) to create new blogger automatically once new user has been created:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Blogger.objects.create(user=instance)
```